# Flutter - Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) | Instance of Response

Tags: flutter, dart

While I'm getting an api, console showing an error like below

> E/flutter (10838): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
>
> E/flutter (10838): Instance of 'Response'
>
> E/flutter (10838): ^
>
> E/flutter (10838):

*this is how I'm getting the api*

```
 Future _fetchPost() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.statusCode);
      print(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }

    setState(() {
      String jsonsDataString = response.toString();
      _data = jsonDecode(jsonsDataString);
      print(_data.toString());
    });

    return "Success";
  }
```

**status code returns 200 and some of the api**

> I/flutter (10838): 200
>
> I/flutter (10838): [{restaurant_id: 1010000001, restaurant_name:
>   Cafe, restaurant_image:
>   http://.unicomerp./1010000001.jpg,
>   table_id: 1, table_name: Riyadh-e 01, branch_name: I
>   Cah, nurl:
>   http://snapittaitt.net/api/menu/10/?org=000001&branch_id=100it=10&offset=20&lang=en,
>   table_menu_list: [{menu_category: Salads and Soup, menu_category_id:
>   11, menu_category_image:
>   http://res.net/iRet/Item/ItemGroup_11.jpg,
>   nexturl:
>   http://snapittappt.net/api/menu/20/?org=1010000001&branch_id=10000001&menuCat=it=10&offset=20&lang=en,
>   category_dishes: [{dish_id: 100001, dish_name: Spinach Salad,
>   dish_price: 7.95, dish_image:
>   http://restaurants.umerp.net///1000000/Items/100000001.jpg,
>   dish_currency: SAR, dish_calories: 15.0, dish_description: Fresh
>   spinach, mushrooms, and hard egg served with warm bacon
>   vinaigrette, dish_Availability: true, dish_Type: 2, nexturl:
>   http://snapitt
>
> E/flutter (10838): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)]
>   Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at
>   character 1)
>
> E/flutter (10838): Instance of 'Response'
>
> E/flutter (10838): ^
>
> E/flutter (10838):

How can I solve this to achieve getting all api?

Any suggestions would be helpful:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change this:

```
String jsonsDataString = response.toString(); // Error: toString of Response is assigned to jsonDataString.
_data = jsonDecode(jsonsDataString);
print(_data.toString());
```

To this:

```
String jsonsDataString = response.body.toString(); // toString of Response's body is assigned to jsonDataString
_data = jsonDecode(jsonsDataString);
print(_data.toString());
```

I hope this helps, in case of any doubt please comment.

Comment: getting success but response data not fetching in flutter while fetching data from get api.

Comment: The use of `toString()` method is redundant. `response.body` already returns a String. `body` is a getter that returns s String.

Answer (score 8):

This same problem occurred to me but for a different reason. As it is a very common problem, I think mentioning it here will help other people who came for a solution searching for the same problem.

I was passing a `Map` of JSON where `String` was required. so, I did this :

```
json.encode(variableWithMapData)
```

and my problem was solved.

Comment: True correct answer or part of a complete answer is this. If you want the JSON string to be decoded into a JSON String later onwards, then the best way to convert the JSON String into a string is by using the `json.encode` otherwise it'll strip out essential character from the resultant String, and you'll never be able to decode it using `json.decode` method of Flutter `import 'dart:convert';` package.

Answer (score 4):

oh, i found this case. so that, i'll make use to convert enter into string response like this :

```
String responseapi = response.body.toString().replaceAll("\n","");
_data = jsonDecode(responseapi);
print(_data);
```

thank you very much for my friend who helped me

Answer (score 2):

Use `json.encode()` for converting jsons to strings instead of using `toString()`

Answer (score 1):

May one of the answer help you out

String jsonsDataString = response.body.toString(); // toString of Response's body is assigned to jsonDataString
final _data = jsonDecode(jsonsDataString);
print(_data.toString());

or

String jsonsDataString = response.data.toString(); // toString of Response's

print(jsonsDataString);

Answer (score 0):

In my Case :

I used `http` instead of `https` which caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late but here is the perfect answer.

This Exception came because of Keys and values which are not properly formatted or you data could have subscripts, superscripts or with/without ==>'' or with/without ==> "".

so, for that you need to first jsonEncode it to make this data Decodable.
If you use directly jsonDecode(); you might encounter this exception.

for Example

saving hash-map result to String
Map result........

> SharedPrefs.setString(ExtraStrings.keyCalculator,jsonEncode(result));

getting value string to object of hash-map

> ```
> String result = SharedPrefs.getString(ExtraStrings.keyCalculator);
>   calculationSaved = CalculationSaved.fromJson(jsonDecode(result));
> ```
>
> CalculationSaved is a model class

without encoding
{Fick’s Cardiac Output:0.345 L/min,Cardiac Index:1.760 l/min/m²}

with encoding
{"Fick’s Cardiac Output":"0.345 L/min","Cardiac Index":"1.760 l/min/m²"}

after json decode and class object
{Cardiac Index: 1.760 l/min/m², Fick’s Cardiac Output: 0.345 L/min}

I hope you get it...

HAPPY CODING....