# Why I'm getting this unexpected excpetion?

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter, dart, geolocation

I'm trying to get distances using the Google Distance Matrix API by the following process:

1. Using the user location as origin
2. Defining the destination by reading the address from a map list
3. Verifying if each distance is lower than 15km and adding map name and distance to lists
4. Printing the data from list of names and distances

**Function created**

```
void pegaDist() async {

String _resultado = "";
int contaMapas = 0;

String _ateOrigem = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=";
String _origem = _enderecoUsuario; //user address
String _ateDestino = "&destinations=";
String _destino = ""; //destinations
String _depoisDestino = "&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
double distancia = 0;


//destination

for(Map map in fornecedoresUpload){ //fornecedores = suppliers

  if(contaMapas < (fornecedoresUpload.length)-1){

    _destino = _destino+map["localizacao"]; //localizacao = address
    _destino = _destino+"|";
    contaMapas = contaMapas +1;


  }else{

    _destino = _destino + map["localizacao"];


  }

}


//API requisition

String url = _ateOrigem +_origem + _ateDestino + _destino + _depoisDestino;
http.Response response = await http.get(url);

Map<String, dynamic> retorno = json.decode(response.body);

//verifying if the distance between the user and the supplier is less than 15 kilometers

for(int i=0 ; i< fornecedoresUpload.length; i++) {

  distancia = double.tryParse(retorno["rows"][0]["elements"][i]["distance"]["value"]); // distancia = distance

  if( distancia < 15000){

    //adding distance and supplier name in the lists

    distancias.add(distancia);
    nomeFornecedoresProximos.add(fornecedoresUpload[i]["nome"]); //nome = name

  }

}

for(int j =0; j< distancias.length; j++){


  print("Nome: " + nomeFornecedoresProximos[j] );
  print("     Distancia: " + distancias[j] );


}  }
```

**Error**

```
E/flutter (21365): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter (21365): <!DOCTYPE html>
E/flutter (21365): ^
E/flutter (21365): 
E/flutter (21365): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1394:5)
E/flutter (21365): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1261:9)
E/flutter (21365): #2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:926:22)
E/flutter (21365): #3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:31:10)
E/flutter (21365): #4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:495:36)
E/flutter (21365): #5      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:153:41)
E/flutter (21365): #6      _EntradaState.pegaDist (package:solisbr/Telas/Entrada.dart:383:41)
E/flutter (21365): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21365): #7      _EntradaState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:solisbr/Telas/Entrada.dart:1095:25)
E/flutter (21365): #8      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706:14)
E/flutter (21365): #9      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:789:36)
E/flutter (21365): #10     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter (21365): #11     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486:11)
E/flutter (21365): #12     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:264:5)
E/flutter (21365): #13     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:199:7)
E/flutter (21365): #14     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:467:9)
E/flutter (21365): #15     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:76:12)
E/flutter (21365): #16     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:117:9)
E/flutter (21365): #17     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8)
E/flutter (21365): #18     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:115:18)
E/flutter (21365): #19     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:7)
E/flutter (21365): #20     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19)
E/flutter (21365): #21     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter (21365): #22     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (21365): #23     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter (21365): #24     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter (21365): #25     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138:13)
E/flutter (21365): #26     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter (21365): #27     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
E/flutter (21365): #28     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:273:10)
E/flutter (21365): #29     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:5)
```

Comment: Maybe this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59539777/flutter-unhandled-exception-formatexception-unexpected-character-at-charact

Comment: It seems because of you are trying to JSON decode a HTML.
Print out the response body before JSON decode may be helpful.

Comment: Your HTTP request might have been rejected, and the response therefore might be an HTML error page.