# Flutter login page authentication using mysql

Tags: mysql, flutter, api, authentication

I am trying to connect my login page so that it fetches data from my users table in mysql and logs the user in but I am having some problems with my code

```
  Future login() async {
    var url = "http://192.168.1.2/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.php";
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
      "username": emailController.text,
      "password": passController.text,
    });
    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    if (data == "Success") {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Login Succesful",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0);
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => StageOne(),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Invalid credentials",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0);
    }
  }
```

Using this code I am getting this error in the debug console no matter what code or method I use I keep getting this error, but for the web version that one of my co workers has made the api seems to be working alright and one can login and logout without any problems.

```
E/flutter ( 5135): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter ( 5135): <br />
E/flutter ( 5135): ^
```

This is my LoginAuth.php file

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Udean
 * Date: 12/14/2019
 * Time: 10:43 AM
 */
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
// Include confi.php
include_once('../func/Data/DAO.php');
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
// Include confi.php
include_once('../func/Data/DAO.php');

$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decode=json_decode($inputJSON);
$username=$decode->username;
$password=$decode->password;
$u = new DAO() ;
  $qur = "select * from users where users_email='$username' and users_password='$password' ";
  $result = mysqli_query($u->conn, $qur);
  $rows = array();
  header('Content-type: application/json');
 
  
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){
     $jsonobj = '{"status":"false","massage":"user not found","data":"null "}';
    echo $jsonobj;

  } else{
   
    $jsonobj = '{"status":"true","massage":"user found","data":'.json_encode(mysqli_fetch_object($result)).'}';
    echo $jsonobj;
  }
 /* while($r = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
      $rows[] = $r;
  }

  $json =$rows;
*/


/* Output header */





?>
```

Comment: Maybe this thread helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539805/9160673

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you.

**Declare your `TextEditingController`**

```
  final TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
```

**Your `signIn` function:**

```
signIn(String username, password) async {
    Map data = {'username': username, 'password': password};
   //in above line 'username' and 'password' are the end Points of the API
    var body = json.encode(data);
    var jsonData;
    var response = await http.post(
      'your login API URL',
      body: body,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Required for CORS support to work
      },
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      if (jsonData != null) {
          print('Login Successfull...!');
          // Or add path to your home page using await method
      }
    } else {
        print('Wrong Credentials...!');
     
    }
  }
```

**Your Button and call your signIn function on button pressed**

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    signIn(usernameController.text, passwordController.text);
  },
  child: Text(
    'Sign In',
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! But I am afraid I am still getting the same error. Could the problem be the php file?

Comment: your API is working correct?

Comment: Yes the api seems to be working fine because it is working for my workmate who made the website version of this app.

Comment: Can you provide me your API url, password n username also
Or try to print json of that url

Comment: Apologies for the late response, but I'm afraid I am using Xampp as a local host for the api, I have edited my original question to include my php file though, I hope you are able to work with that.

Comment: Here is the link though incase you can find a way to work with it, localhost/testlive/LoginAuth.php and an example username and password is 
Username: josh@test.com
Password: Pass123#

Comment: can you tell me your API response is working or localhost machine or Postman? if its working then try to print response on your console

Comment: Oh it seems it is not actually working because when I try to print the response it is giving me the same error.

Comment: your login API is working or not ?

Comment: I think I may have found the problem but I am not sure(I'm still very new to programming) , I used flutter devtools to see if I am getting a response and this is what I am getting. The GET method is returning ws, could this be the problem?https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LLMH6eCEGzAT1HBSADLofereAkbFr2ac/view?usp=sharing

Comment: connect me [here](https://www.linkedin.com/in/ravindra-patil-789570194/) If you used LinkedInI will join you with video meeting

Comment: Alright great, I sent you a connection request